# segmentation violation - stopping myself in Octave

Tags: recursion, octave, numerical-integration

I have the following code in Octave to try to implement adaptive quadrature using Simpson's method:

```
function integral = adaptive2(f, a, b, TOL, count)
max_count = 20;
disp("hello world");
disp(count);
h = (b-a)/2;
x_1 = a;
x_2 = (b-a)/2;
x_3 = b;

w_0 = a;
w_1 = (b-a)/4;
w_2 = (b-a)/2;
w_3 = 3*(b-a)/4;
w_4 = b;


initial_1 = (f(x_1) + 4*f(x_2) + f(x_3));
i1 = (h/3) * initial_1;

initial_2 = (f(w_0) + 4*f(w_1) + 2*f(w_2) + 4*f(w_3) + f(w_4));
i2 = (h/6) * initial_2;
disp(i1);
disp(i2);
if count == max_count
    integral = i2;
    return;
endif
if abs(i1 - i2) < (10 * TOL)
    integral = i2;
    return;
endif

count = count + 1;
disp(count);
disp(TOL);
integral = (adaptive2(f, a, (b+a)/2, TOL/2, count) + adaptive2(f, (b+a)/2,     b, TOL/2, count));
return;
```

With the paramaters:

```
f = @(x) 1/sqrt(x)
a = 10^-4
b = 1
TOL = 10^-6
count = 0
```

And I get the following error:

```
panic segmentation violation - stopping myself
```

What's occurring in this code that I need to fix? Is it an infinite loop? Are the recursion calls at the end improper?

Comment: GNU Octave should never segfault so this is a bug. Which version, OS and build are you using?

Comment: It does not crash here (octave 3.8.2 on linux), but it seems stuck in a loop. You could try to reduce `max_count` to debug it with less recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to reproduce this segfault, which should not be occurring:**

About my setup:

1. Linux 4.1.15-gentoo-r1
2. GNU Octave, version 3.8.2
3. Putty Release 63
4. X11 forwarding tool: xming 6.9.0.31

Code to reproduce the error:

```
octave:1> plot(1)
Insufficient GL support
Insufficient GL support
panic: Segmentation fault -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
save to 'octave-workspace' complete
Segmentation fault
```

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Turn on two factor authentication on the gentoo box.
2. Turn on xming for x11 forwarding, map it to localhost:0
3. Login to the Gentoo Linux instance with putty.
4. Run octave commandline and run plot(1)
5. Get the above error.

Observations:

1. When I remove xming and putty from the equation the plot shows correctly on the localhost without any errors.
2. If I run without xming, then the error is received, as expected:

   ```
   gnuplot: unable to open display 'localhost:10.0'
   gnuplot: X11 aborted.
   ```
3. When I turn off two factor authentication in linux, the error no longer occurs.

The X11 windows worked fine before I enabled 2 factor authentication on the gentoo box.  When I turned off the 2 factor authentication, it works fine again.

**Conclusion:**

Two factor authentication knocks out octave's ability to do X11 forwarding on plots.  It could be some kind of protection feature.